# Update webflux stream in realtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8

I want to update the stream I have created using webflux in realtime. Below is my code:-

```
public Flux<UserEvent> getEvents(String userId)
    {
        return findById(userId)
                .flatMapMany(user -> {
                    Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
                    Flux<UserEvent> userEventFlux =
                            Flux.fromStream(
                                    Stream.generate(() -> new UserEvent(LocalDateTime.now(), user))
                            );
                    return Flux.zip(interval, userEventFlux)
                            .map(Tuple2::getT2);
                });
    }
```

But it fetches the data from repo only once and keeps sending same data again and again.
Then I tried with this:-

```
public Flux<UserEvent> getEvents(String userId)
{
    Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    Flux<UserEvent> userEventFlux =
            Flux.fromStream(
                    Stream.generate(() -> {
                                        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
                                        findById(userId).subscribe(user->users.add(user));
                                        try{Thread.sleep(2000);}catch(Exception e){}
                                        return new UserEvent(LocalDateTime.now(), users.get(0));
                                    }
                    )
            );
    return Flux.zip(interval, userEventFlux)
            .map(Tuple2::getT2);
}
```

But I get index 0 size zero error on console. Since I am unable to figure out how to get user object out of Mono and then pass it to flux, I am sort of stuck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a brute force mechanism to update the stream in realtime. But, IDK, why it feels like there has to be some cleaner solution. My current updated code is below.

```
public Flux<UserEvent> getEvents(String userId)
{
    Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    Flux<UserEvent> userEventFlux =
            Flux.fromStream(
                    Stream.generate(() -> {
                                        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
                                        findById(userId).subscribe(user->users.add(user));
                                        while(users.size() == 0){
                                            try{Thread.sleep(2000);}catch(Exception e){}
                                        }
                                        return new UserEvent(LocalDateTime.now(), users.get(0));
                                    }
                    )
            );
    return Flux.zip(interval, userEventFlux)
            .map(Tuple2::getT2);
}
```

Please let me know in case if there is a better solution.